# Switched to a new laptop and suddenly my Vue project fails to compile with ES6 syntax errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuex

As the title says I just got a new laptop and something is not right. I pulled my Vue project from GitHub and ran npm install, then npm run dev.

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                               1:38:10 PM

error  in ./src/pages/index.vue

Syntax Error: Unexpected token (97:4)

 95 |   },
 96 |  computed: {
>    97 |     ...mapState({
  |     ^
98 |       cityData: state => state.city
99 |     }),
100 |     cityNameData () {



@ ./src/pages/index.vue 9:0-105 10:0-118
@ ./src/router/index.js
@ ./src/main.js
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?    
http://localhost:3000 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/main.js
```

It looks like its hanging on ES6 syntax. My node version is v8.11.3 and my npm version is 5.6.0.

What have I missed?

Comment: Dont think it is laptop problem , but may be editor's problem

Comment: Are you using Vue 1x or 2x?

Comment: It may be related to the spacing and/or identation that your IDE is failing to recognize

Comment: Spread syntax has been supported since around [node 5](https://node.green/#ES2015-syntax-spread-syntax-for-iterable-objects).  Are there pipe literals " | " in your source code though?  It's strange that the error is indented the way it is and that it is pointed at a pipe.

Comment: @zero298 that's the standard error log format for a vuejs exception in console, it's not a node exception.

Comment: *Object* spread syntax is not part of ES6, it's part of ES9 - released this year.

Answer (score 0):

That problem really looks like it's babel (the transpiler).

Depending on your project's configuration, you might have a .babelrc file or babel config in the package.json.

Here you have a similar issue:

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-loader-unexpected-token-error-for-using-spread-operator-on-my-vue-component/10241/6

You might have forgotten (or ignored) to include it into your repository.